# metabox dosn't save with checkbox of post_type values order by taxonomy

Tags: metabox

Please me!!!! Itried thow weeks and I search but without any result I can't save meta box that has both checkbox i need your help as soon as possible 
this is my code callback my metabox :

```
$terms = get_terms( 'type_livre', $terms = get_terms( 'type_livre', 
  array( 
  array(
`
<div>
<?php 
  $terms = get_terms( 'type_livre', 
  array(
        'orderby'    => 'id',
        'hide_empty' => 1 
    ) 
);

foreach( $terms as $term ) {


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'livre',
        'type_livre'  => $term->slug  taxonomy
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );


    echo'<h2 class="h2 faq-cat">' . $term->name . '</h2>';



        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" value="<?php the_title() ; ?>" >

            <label for="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <?php the_title() ; ?>
            </label>

            <label for="Qte_livre" style="margin-left: 352px;buttom">
                <?php echo 'Qte'; ?>
            </label>

            <input type="number" id="Qte_livre" name="Qte_livre" style="margin-left: 452px;"/>


        <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata(); 

        echo '<hr/>';


    wp_reset_postdata();

} 
`
```

Comment: You said one thing your code said other thing. take time and explain little-bit more that make sense.

however. I didn't find anything about metabox in your code and also you have using extra `wp_reset_postdata()`

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how can i save this metabox please helpe me. This Is my code :

```
<?php

function book_function_meta_box(){
 add_meta_box('book_meta_box', 'more Infos', 'book_meta_box_callback', 'book', 'normal');
}

add_action('add_meta_box', 'book_add_meta_box');


function book_meta_box_callback()
{
    wp_nonce_field('book_save_meta_box_data', 'book_nonce_name');

    $terms = get_terms(
        'category',
        array(
            'orderby'    => 'id',
            'hide_empty' => 1 // hide categories with no posts
        )
    );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {


        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'book',
            'category'  => $term->slug
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);


        echo '<h2 class="h2 faq-cat">' . $term->name . '</h2>';

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $livre_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID()));

            $qte_slug = $livre_slug . 'qte';

            ?>
            <div>

                <label for="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <?php echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>'; ?>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $livre_slug; ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" value="<?php the_title(); ?>" <?php if (isset($_POST[$livre_slug])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />

                <label for="<?php echo $qte_slug; ?>" style="margin-left: 352px;buttom">
                    <?php echo 'Qte'; ?>
                </label>

                <input type="number" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" name="<?php echo $qte_slug; ?>" style="margin-left: 452px;" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $qte_slug, true)); ?>" />

            </div>
            <?php



            wp_reset_postdata();
        endwhile;

        // use reset postdata to restore the original query
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```